# use PHP to Load 1 row in database, but with

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a question about how I can take a single row from a database and for every value of the row, add the character "|"

now, I use this method to load all of the value in a row:

```
$username = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE ID = $id");
while($usernameDB = mysqli_fetch_array($username))
  {
  echo $usernameDB['username'];
  echo "|";
  }
$lastname = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `lastname` FROM `users` WHERE ID = $id");
while($lastnameDB = mysqli_fetch_array($lastname))
  {
  echo $lastnameDB['lastname'];
  echo "|";
  }
```

with this method, I will have a echo like:

myname|mylastname|

and is working good... the problem is when I need to load 40 value... I think is not a good idea to repeat 40 times ...

is possible to load a single row and add a script like "for every value, add |" like my example...?

thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$username = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `username`,`lastname` FROM `users` WHERE ID = $id");
$char =  "|";
while($usernameDB = mysqli_fetch_array($username))
  {
  echo $usernameDB['username'];
  echo $char;
  echo $usernameDB['lastname'];
  echo $char; 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this all in single SQL query.  Try this:

```
SELECT group_concat(`username` separator '|') as usernames,
       group_concat(lastname separator '|') as lastnames
FROM `users`
WHERE ID = $id";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ID = $id");
if ($usernameDB = mysqli_fetch_assoc($username)) {
  echo implode('|', $usernameDB);
}else{
  echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MySQL using select into.. and read from this file

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/output.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users; // Add condition to restrict to 1 row
```

OR

With PHP
Get the result set as an array and implode using "|" separator.